# Подставить ключ в словарь из другого словаря в шаблоне Django?

Tags: python, django

У менять есть словарь money, который хранит айди и число. Есть результат запроса `payments`, который перебираем в цикле. Айди `payment` совпадает с айди `money`. Вот хочу подставить `payment.id` в айдишник money. Как это сделать? Потому что сейчас у меня вот такая ошибка...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**HTML-код**

```
    {% for payment in payments %}
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
    <td>{{ payment.id }}</td>
    <td>{{ payment.deal.service.contractor.name }} </td>
   <td>{{ money.{{payment.id}} }} {{ payment.currency.iso_name }}</td>
   <td>{{ payment.payment_date }}</td>
   {% if payment.status == 'success' %}
  <td>Выполнен</td>
   {% elif payment.status == 'decline' %}
   <td>Отклонён</td>
  {% elif payment.status == 'refund' %}
  <td>Возврат</td>
      {% elif payment.status == 'pending_callback' %}
  <td>Возврат</td>
  {% else %}
  <td>{{ payment.status }}</td>
    {% endif %}
    </tr>
   {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{{ money.{{payment.id}} }}
```

Так не делается. 
Я бы на твоём месте сформировал нужные данные во view, а потом уже выводил их в template.
Если делать в template, то можно использовать custom filter
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-template-tags/